# How to find network details in the ipad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

I have to find to which network the ipad is currently connected through the ipad application. is it possible through the reachability code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the SSID of the wifi network?
That's not possible.

For checking internet/intranet connection, use the reachability, and specify your own server (on the intranet) or a public server (on the internet) to check if you can reach it.

Comment: i need to know whether the ipad is connected to internet or intranet or some other network

Comment: i have a wifi network that is authenticated. when the ipad is connected in that network i want my ipad app to bypass the login and use those credentials to login to my app. is that possible?

Comment: You could check to see if a particular server on your wifi network is available and if so, you would know that you are connected to the wifi network.  Then you could do you login code as appropriate.  If you can't find the server, then display a different login screen.

Comment: i can check whether wifi is connected to ipad. but whether it is connected through particular user login, is there a way to find out  that?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that through iOS.